# Adding an array of objects to session storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, session-storage

I've been trying to save an array with the contents of the cart on a website. Both the object and the array are filled as expected, however when checking the sessionStorage, there's an array with an empty object, I've been at this for a while, taking on and off breaks but am currently losing my sanity.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
var cartContents = [];
var obj = new Object();

setTimeout(function(){ 

    
    var prodId = JSON.stringify(meta.product.id); //meta.product.id
    var prodName = $('h1.product-single__title')[0].innerText; //$('h1.product-single__title')[0].innerText
    var quantity = "1"; 
    var unitPrice = $('span.price-item')[0].innerText.substring(1); //$('span.price-item')[0].innerText.substring(1)
    var currency = $('span.price-item')[0].innerText.charAt(0); //$('span.price-item')[0].innerText.charAt(0)
    
    
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'id', {
        value: prodId,
        writable: false
    });
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
        value: prodName,
        writable: false
    });
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'quantity', {
        value: quantity,
        writable: false
      });
      Object.defineProperty(obj, 'unitPrice', {
        value: unitPrice,
        writable: false
      });
      Object.defineProperty(obj, 'currency', {
        value: currency,
        writable: false
      });
      cartContents.push(obj);
      console.log(cartContents)
      sessionStorage.setItem("cartContents", (JSON.stringify(cartContents)));
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are going to stringify it anyway, you don't need the Object class modification. Use this simple approach

```js
var cartContents = [];
var obj = new Object();

setTimeout(function(){ 

    
    var prodId = JSON.stringify(meta.product.id); //meta.product.id
    var prodName = $('h1.product-single__title')[0].innerText; //$('h1.product-single__title')[0].innerText
    var quantity = "1"; 
    var unitPrice = $('span.price-item')[0].innerText.substring(1); //$('span.price-item')[0].innerText.substring(1)
    var currency = $('span.price-item')[0].innerText.charAt(0); //$('span.price-item')[0].innerText.charAt(0)
    
    

      obj.id = prodId;
      obj.name = prodName;
      obj.unitPrice = unitPrice;
      obj.currency = currency
      cartContents.push(obj);
      console.log(cartContents)
      sessionStorage.setItem("cartContents", (JSON.stringify(cartContents)));
    }, 3000);
```